# Carregar uma página dentro de outra

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

Tenho uma página de layout onde quero carregar informações no botão de notificações.

Para isso, fiz uma action no controller para retornar uma PartialView onde será feita uma consulta no bd procurando as informações.

Como carrego essa página dentro do layout de forma que passe pela action e carregue as informações?

```
public IActionResult Notificacoes()
        {
            var pessoa = (from p in _context.ApplicationUsers where p.Id == _userManager.GetUserId(User) select p).SingleOrDefault();
            var notificacoes = _context.PublicacaoAmigos.Include(m => m.Pessoa).Where(n => n.Status != "Visto").Where(n => n.Amigo == pessoa);
            return PartialView("Notificacoes", notificacoes);
        }
```

publicacoes.html

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {

<li>
      <div class="media-body">
          <strong class="notification-title"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Pessoa.Nome) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Pessoa.Sobrenome) marcou você </strong>
          <p class="notification-desc">em uma publicação</p>
            @Html.ActionLink("Ver Publicação", "Publicacoes", "Materiais", new{id = item.Pessoa.Id })
          <div class="notification-meta">
            <small class="timestamp">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Data)</small>
          </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    }
```

layout.html

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="lista_notificacoes">

   @await Html.PartialAsync("Publicacoes")

    </ul>
```

Comment: Você recebe algum erro ?

Comment: Um erro no meu foreach  @foreach (var item in Model) porque ao que parece não está passando pela action: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Já tentou usar o RenderAction() ?

Comment: Sim, parece que o RenderAction() foi trocado pelo ViewComponent mas não sei como usar: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: `@await Component.InvokeAsync("Publicacoes")`